# What is the best solution (library) for a biography / historic presentation?

Tags: html, css

I'm searching for a library which provide a good and nice solution to create historic page for company's website.

Example : 
Historic Page:
[image]

Comment: Flagging this question to be closed because of SO policy: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: *[PokerFace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bESGLojNYSo)*